# not able to see the DAG in Web UI

Tags: airflow

I have created a new DAG using the following code. It is calling a python script.

Code:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from builtins import range
    import airflow
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from airflow.models import DAG
    from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
    from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

    args = {
        'owner': 'admin'
    }

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id='workflow_file_upload', default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None)

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='testairflow',
        bash_command='python /root/DataLake_Scripts/File_Upload_GCP.py',
        dag=dag)
```

I have placed it in $airflowhome/dags folder.

after that I have run :

airflow scheduler

I am trying to see the DAG in WebUI however it is not visible there. There is no error coming.

Comment: Is it possible that your DAG is hidden?
What happens when you click "show paused DAGs" at the bottom left of the main UI?

Comment: Is the dag file also present on the webserver's `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dag`? DAGs need to be synced to both.

Comment: Hi Brathe   DAG is not visible after clicking on "Show paused DAGs"

Comment: yes dag file is present in $AIRFLOW_HOME/dag  on all the nodes

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same issue.
I figured out that the problem is in initial sqlite db. I suppose it's some feature of airflow 1.10.3
Anyway I solved the problem using postgresql backend. 
These links will help you:

- [link](https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-ddc087482c14)
- [link](https://medium.com/a-r-g-o/installing-apache-airflow-on-ubuntu-aws-6ebac15db211)
- [link](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/156)

All instructions are suitable for python 3.
You'll see your DAG after execution of 'airflow webserver' and 'airflow scheduler' commands.
Also notice that you should call 'sudo service postgresql restart' exactly before 'airflow initdb' command.